# Fetching past messages into a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm currently trying to add a feature to my bot to go through a channel and fetch all the messages in that channel, outputting it into a TXT file if possible. (I am a bit of a beginner in JS and nodeJS but I've been developing this bot for almost a year so I have a decent grasp on how it works, still learning though)

I currently have it set up so when I send a command in Discord it will fetch the latest 100 messages of a channel, but doesn't output it anywhere currently.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'fetchtest') {
        client.channels.get(<channelID>).fetchMessages({ limit: 100 })
            .then(messages => console.log(`Received ${messages.size} messages`))
            .catch(console.error);
    }
});
```

What I need help on is figuring out how to 'loop' the code so it saves each 100 messages until it hits the first message, and having it output that into a text file with `<user>: <message>` format. Is there a good guide to follow for this or a basic rundown of what I should do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to do this in a simple way, you could just get the first message of the collection returned in your first request, get it's ID and use it as the value of parameter **before** of the **ChannelLogsQueryOptions** (it's the object you're passing as parameter to change the default message fetch limit).

[Here some reference](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelLogsQueryOptions)

Also, just to help you understand the logic of this, some code sample:

```js
// Async function to handle promises like synchronous piece of code
async function loadUsers() {
  let page = 1; // First page (begin point)
  
  // Infinite loop because "we don't know the total of users in the API"
  while(true) {
    // Request to our fake API and getting the only property of the returned JSON that matters to this example
    let userList = (await fetch(`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${page}`).then( response => response.json())).data;
    
    // Check if we have an empty response or not
    if(userList.length){
      // This is just vanilla JavaScript for inserting some DOM Elements, ignore it, just to add some visual output to this example
      userList.forEach( user => {
        let section = document.querySelector('section'),
            userElement = document.createElement('p');
        
        userElement.innerText = user.email;
        section.appendChild( userElement );
      });
    } else {
      // If we do got an empty response we break out of this loop and the function execution ends
      break;    
    }
    
    // Increment our page number so we can achieve new data, instead of doing the same request
    page++;
  }
}

// Execute the function declared above
loadUsers();
```

```html
<section></section>
```

In my code example, i use a [fake API](https://reqres.in/) who gives me information page per page (and in addiction i pretend it is not telling me the total amount of pages, so this snippet can best relate to your problem) and then i add every user email received until i got an empty response, which is my stop condition (a.k.a break out of the "while true" infinite loop).

In your situation, doing something slightly similar to the snippet, but in the specific context of Discord.js may solve your problem satisfactorily, since it seems there isn't anything in the documentation of Discord.js about retrieving the total amount of messages of a TextChannel.